# BASH get file extension without GET params?

Tags: bash, variables, url

I have a way to get a file extension using the below

```
url='http://foo.com/index.php?foo=bar' 
ext="${url##*.}" 
echo $ext // php?foo=bar
```

But am having an issue removing the GET params from
this, how would I go this in my ext param?

I am using BASH v4+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
ext='php?foo=bar'
echo "${ext%\?*}"
php
```

Comment: @Anubhav Can You please help me to understand me this

Comment: Like 9 BASH questions you've got for me now btw, lol. YOU SUIR ARE THE BASH-MAN!

Comment: @Ashish: Yes sure: `%` strips out trailing part of a BASH string and `\?*` is the glob pattern for removal part.

Comment: I got. just like awk with a seperator.. If you didn't mind then how can I get data after `?`

Comment: @Ashish: For that you can use: `echo "${ext#*\?}"`

Comment: I would use `%%` to ensure you strip all the parameters, in case one of them contains a `?` itself (or is `?` not a legal character following the first one?).

Comment: @anubhava: I knew I am asking for more.. I guess if you don't mind can you show getting filename from url directly in one shot instead of storing value of 1 variable and then again process and store it in 3rd

Comment: @Ashish: That can be possible only by using sed/awk not in pure BASH.

Comment: Also I didn't use `%%` because in a URL there is supposed to be only one `?`

Comment: `echo $url | awk -F '?' '{print $1}' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}' ` this is what I thought of posting

Answer (score 2):

Remove the suffix of the result including the first `?`.

```
get_params=${ext%%\?*}
```

You can also use a regular expression to get the extension in one operation.

```
[[ $url =~ \.([^?.]+)\? ]]
ext=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Comment: doesn't work, try `url='http://foo.com/index.php?foo=bar&bar=baz' ; [[ $url =~ \.([^?.]+)\? ]] ; ext=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} echo $ext`

Comment: Works for me in `bash` 3.2 and 4.2.

Comment: What is `ext` being set to for you, if not `php`?

Comment: it was `php?foo=bar&bar=baz` maybe the globals weren't writing correctly

Comment: I somehow agreee with BASH_REMATCH

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `sed` for non bash v4+ users :

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

url='http://foo.com/index.php?foo=bar'
ext=$(echo $url|sed "s/.*\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\?.*/\1/g")
echo $ext
$ ./test.sh 
php
```